# Django - Display the number of users currently watching a live stream

Tags: javascript, django, web, video-streaming, live

I'm developing a Django site for a sports streaming service. It is necessary to display the number of users who are currently watching the broadcast. You can watch the broadcast only after authorization.

What is the best way to implement this?

At the moment I think that the best solution would be to send a js request to the Django server, but I think there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Well , You can even use GA-4(Beta version for Google Analytics) or GA-3(Stable) to get the live visitors count. But this may end up carrying more resources. Apart from live count you can get access to many things as in traffic , No. of times linked is hit. ETC....ETC.